# xfce notifications not working

Tags: xfce, notifications

Whenever I run `notify-send`, nothing happens. When I run `xfce4-notifyd-config` and click preview, I get dialogues saying:

> Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process
>   org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1

and

> (xfce4-notifyd-config:16007): Gdk-WARNING **:
>   gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sourcing /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh from your xinit.

Comment: That file exists. It's contents are: `#!/bin/sh

systemctl --user import-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY

if which dbus-update-activation-environment >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        dbus-update-activation-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
fi`

Comment: Delete the older one and replace it with a new one, but make sure to copy and paste the original

Comment: I still get the same error after touching the file and rebooting.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part where you said source. I just touched it.

Comment: @Marcel, no problem my man stay real and have fun